# Why is Live Sass Compiler breaking my many-to-one source mappings?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

## Goal

Compile many `.sass` files to one `.css` file, where all `.sass` and `.css` files are in the same directory.

## Problem summary

I'm trying to compile many `.sass` files to one `.css` file, all located within the same directory, like this:

```
- app
  - static
    - css
      - _base.sass
      - _header.sass
      - _layout.sass
      - _map.sass
      - _modal.sass
      - _windows.sass
      - main.v0.css
      - main.v0.css.map
      - main.v0.sass
```

I'm using the VSCode extension Live Sass Compiler, which has worked seamlessly in the past for what I'm doing but all of a sudden it's breaking my source mappings. I also can't remember/figure out how to do a many to one Sass compilation at the command line, with the specific constraint of keeping both the .sass and .css files in the same directory.

At this stage, every time I use Live Sass Compiler to compile, my git history shows these changes (see screenshots), which seem to be breaking the site. When I load my page after making changes in this way, all the styling for my site stops working.

## Findings

From what I can deduce, it's wiping all the previously compiled styling from `main.v0.css` and replacing it with mapping information. In `main.v0.css.map` it seems to be stripping `sourceRoot` information, changing `sources` from `main.v0.css` to `main.v0.sass`, and changing `file` from `main.v0.css` to `main.v0.sass` (so just switching those two for some reason).

Can anyone help me? Maybe this broke with the last VSCode update or something?

[image: main.v0.css working tree]

[image: main.v0.css.map working tree]

[image: main.v0.css.map working tree, view of prop "file"]

Comment: How do you have Live Sass Compiler configured?